# Boot Options (GRUB Menu) Not Showing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Back when i first installed ubuntu,all was well,whenever i would start my computer,i'd see my boot options,windows and ubuntu,then choose one,but recently,the boot menu hasn't been showing up,whenever i start my pc it boots ubuntu straight away with no options menu.

I suspect this is because i disabled Secure Boot,since it started happening when i disabled it,since i did,every time i boot it says "Booting in Insecure mode",is this the cause?If so,how can i re-enable it safely?

Comment: Probably not related to UEFI Secure Boot. Did Windows do an update? That update can turn fast start up back on setting hibernation flag. Then grub2's os-prober cannot find the NTFS partition(s). Check Windows fast start up setting. Also Windows update may update UEFI which often resets many UEFI settings to defaults. You may need to review those. ( I keep a list as my system needs many). https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

To force a grub menu, you should edit the file /etc/default/grub
and modify options:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

And run

```
sudo update-grub
```

You may use `grub-customizer` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but are you sure this is safe?I This might  sound stupid but ubuntu is my first non-windows OS and not everything has gone smoothy for me,i'm a bit paranoid and feel like even the slightest typo will destroy my computer.Will this interfere  with any other functionalities?